# Hash Tables: Ransom Note hackerrank

Tags: java

Harold is a kidnapper who wrote a ransom note, but now he is worried it will be traced back to him through his handwriting. He found a magazine and wants to know if he can cut out whole words from it and use them to create an untraceable replica of his ransom note. The words in his note are case-sensitive and he must use only whole words available in the magazine. He cannot use substrings or concatenation to create the words he needs.

Given the words in the magazine and the words in the ransom note, print Yes if he can replicate his ransom note exactly using whole words from the magazine; otherwise, print No.

For example, the note is "Attack at dawn". The magazine contains only "attack at dawn". The magazine has all the right words, but there's a case mismatch. The answer is .

Sample Input 0

6 4
give me one grand today night
give one grand today
Sample Output 0

Yes
Sample Input 1

6 5
two times three is not four
two times two is four
Sample Output 1

No

My code 5/22 test cases failed :(

I can't figure out why 5 failed.

```
static void checkMagazine(String[] magazine, String[] note) {

    int flag = 1;
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(String word: magazine) {
        if(!wordMap.containsKey(word)) {
            wordMap.put(word, 1);
        } else
            wordMap.put(word,wordMap.get(word)+1);
    }
    for(String word: note){
        if(!wordMap.containsKey(word)){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        } 
            else wordMap.remove(word, wordMap.get(word));       
    }

    if(flag == 0)
        System.out.println("No");
    else
      System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Looks like you do not correctly process cases when `note` has several occurrences of the same word

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because instead of decrementing the count of the words in the magazine when you retrieve one, you're removing all counts of that word completely.  Try this:

```
for(String word: note){
    if(!(wordMap.containsKey(word) && wordMap.get(word) > 0)){
        flag = 0;
        break;
    } 
    else wordMap.put(word, wordMap.get(word)-1);       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`wordMap` is a frequency table and gives word counts.
However for every word in the note, you must decrease the word count instead of entirely removing the entry. Only when the word count reaches 0 one could remove the entry.

*An other isssue is the case-sensitivity. Depending on the requirements you may need to convert all words to lowercase.*

```
        else {
            wordMap.computeIfPresent(word, (k, v) -> v <= 1? null : v - 1);       
        }
```

This checks that the old value `v` is above 1 and then decreases it, or else returns a null value signaling to delete the entry.

The frequency counts can be done:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
for(String word: magazine) {
    wordMap.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, this implementation is simplier

```
static boolean checkMagazine(String[] magazine, String[] note) {
    List<String> magazineCopy = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(magazine));

    for (String word : note)
    {
        if (magazineCopy.contains(word)) {
            magazineCopy.remove(word);
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I suppose your error is here:

```
else wordMap.remove(word, wordMap.get(word));
```

you are removing the word from the map, instead of decreasing the number of such words and only if the number reaches 0, you should remove the word from the map.

Comment: I think you did not see, that words may occure more than once in the note and then there must be sufficient repetitions in the magazine.

Comment: I think you don't see my implementation - these cases are there. A word can be in a list numerous of times.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. One could even make it faster by sorting and doing a binarySearch.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But before we need to sort the list, but after that the will be able to find values much faster than just in regular `contains`

Comment: Honestly said: it would be **much better** to make a collection on the ransom note, and remove words walking trough the magazine, removing not words, till no word of the ransom note remains.

Comment: That's interesting. I'd really like to see the arguments toward that. Maybe I'm missing something,but here's my speculation about the topic: Suppose we have M words in the magazine and N words in the note. In case walking through the note, we can stop the algorithm at the very first word, so only in N comparisons. And the worst case is `Σ(M-i)(N-i)`, where `i=1..N` compares, when the magazine has all the words from the note.

Comment: But when we iterate through magazine, we can't stop earlier than we've checked all the words in the magazine (or check the note for emptiness on each iteration, but that gives us M more comparisons), so the worst is M*N, the best - the same Σ(M-i)(N-i).
The only problem I see with removing from the magazine is that `ArrayList` is used and removing from it isn't so efficient, so less remove operations is better.

Comment: This implementation is indeed "simpler," but it is much less efficient, as the OP's approach is O(n+m) and every String.contains(word) search is already O(m) by itself, making this solution more like O(m*n)

Comment: Yes, that's completelly true. But on the other hand, because it's Java, we got burden of boxing/unboxing, plus additional comparisons amount of words to zero at every word. So yes, OP's algorithm is more efficient on big amount of words. By the way, is the `m` from `O(n+m)` taken from the hash map creation?

Comment: @JoopEggen, I think I've got your previous message.  `make a collection` you meant `make a map`, did you? Because I thought you meant make a `make a List collection` and iterate through it.

Comment: @Michel_T Yes, regardless of which is m and n, it's linear time to create the map, and linear time to iterate through the note.

Comment: Map is superior to List. However I wanted to stress that storing the ransom note does not store unused words and will yield a positive outcome faster.

Answer (score -1):

Python Solution

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, ransom):
    magazine.sort()
    ransom.sort()
    for word in ransom:
        if word not in magazine:
            flag = False
            break
        else:
            magazine.remove(word)
        flag = True

    if (flag):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```